# Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I tried installing `matplotlib` whl file in python 3.6 on windows but I all I got was this error:

`C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\wheel\pep425tags.py:77: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect warn=(impl == 'cp')):`

I tried debugging it but it seems to be a real issue here:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3383

Could someone please let me know how do I solve this error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Turns out 3383 got closed in favor of https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3535

Comment: And 3535 got closed by a newer version of Python for Windows.

Comment: But I'm using python 3.7.0, just installed, and it is still there. Hmm.

Comment: `3.10` and still there!

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer is irrelevant (and outdated) to the original question, people come here after Googling for this very error.

At the end of the day, it usually turn out to be some kind of package compilation error when using `pip install .` and build related installs. Most likely because the build config was made primarily for a unix OS and not windows. Who knows. So try to use a different compiler or make sure you have installed all the required compiler components. I.e. for Windows that is a >7 GB of *Visual Studio* C/C++ development/tools install. You may also try the 1 GB MinGW install.

However, the following official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#debugging-builds) clearly state the use for **`Py_DEBUG`**.

> Compiling the interpreter with the Py_DEBUG macro defined produces what is generally meant by a debug build of Python. Py_DEBUG is enabled in the Unix build by adding `--with-pydebug` to the `./configure` command. It is also implied by the presence of the not-Python-specific `_DEBUG` macro. When Py_DEBUG is enabled in the Unix build, compiler optimization is **disabled**.

Further info can be found here:

- https://docs.python.org/3/using/configure.html#debug-build